# Error: data and hash must be strings in login

Tags: node.js, hash, bcrypt

I checked my code with postman and it gives this error

***(node:6548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data and hash must be strings
at Object.compareSync (H:\Chale\Angular Projects\mean-mysql-login-reg\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:170:15)
at H:\Chale\Angular Projects\mean-mysql-login-reg\routes\Users.js:58:19
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:6548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6548) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.***

This is my code

routes/Users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const users = express.Router();
const cors = require('cors');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const User = require('../model/User');
users.use(cors());

process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'secret';

//register
users.post('/register', (req,res) => {

    const userData = {
        first_name : req.body.first_name,
        last_name : req.body.last_name,
        email : req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }

    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email
        }
    })
        .then(user => {
            if(user){
                const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(userData.password, 10)
                userData.password = hash
                User.create(userData)
                .then( user => {
                    let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY,{
                        expiresIn:1440
                    })
                    res.json({ token : token })
                })
                .catch( err=>{
                    res.send('error 50555' + error)
                })
            }else{
                res.json({ error:'User already exists!' })
            }  
            })
        .catch(err=>{
            res.send('error:' + err)
        })
})

//login- ***Error is somewhere here in login section***
users.post('/login1', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email : req.body.email
        }
    })
    .then(user => {
        if(bcrypt.compareSync(" " + req.body.password, user.password)) {
            let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                expiresIn: 1440
            })
            res.json({ token: token })
        }else{
            res.send('User does not exist!')
        }
    })
  
})

module.exports = users
```

model/User.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../database/db.js')

module.exports = db.sequelize.define(
    'user',
    {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        first_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        last_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    }
)
```

What is the exact error in this code?

Happy, if someone can help me.
I am new to bcrypt and hash.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint at the line `if(bcrypt.compareSync(" " + req.body.password, user.password))` and look at both `req.body.password` and `user.password`?

Comment: @Anatoly I tried it but it still the same. Error:data and hash must be strings

Comment: What does it mean you tried it? What values did you see?

Comment: @Anatoly I edited the code like you said and run. like this if(bcrypt.compareSync(" " + req.body.password, user.password)). Is it not what you told? I got the idea like that.

Comment: I just wanted that you look at these two variables.  Can you add `console.log(req.body.password, user.password)` before `if(bcrypt.compareSync`?

Comment: @Anatoly req.body.password is getting the exact password but user.password is getting 0.

Comment: You mean user.password equals to zero (with number type)?

Comment: @Anatoly yes it is.

Comment: How so? I suspect that's the source of the error. You can try to convert `user.password` to string to pass to `bcrypt.compareSync`